# How to sort a python list by checking if it matches a given pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

Sorry for my english.

I'm making a tkinter program in python but I've stuck on the way of sorting a list. Let me explain you.

I want to build a function that takes a (user input) list of strings as argument and returns the same list in a different order according to if their elements matches a certain dictionary keys.

I've put in the dict the order associated to each key.

```
dic=dict(organiza=1,autor=1,direct=1,docen=1,exp=1,dirig=1,ponen=1,fecha=2,día=2,dia=2,cuándo=2,cuando=2,lugar=3,sitio=3,locali=3,situa=3,direcci=3,ubica=3,web=4,link=4,enlace=4,página=4,pagina=4)
```

I want that, if I pick up a list like:

```
    lis=['TITLE:BLAH,BLAH..', 'web: www.something.es', 'situación: UCM University', 'Director: Someone', 'Fecha: some date']
```

The output should be:

```
    ['TITLE:BLAH,BLAH..','Director: Someone', 'Fecha: some date', 'situación: UCM University' 'web: www.something.es']
```

i.e, the order I want is by "TITLE (this is the first one ever, not change), Director, Fecha, Situación, Web" or their meaning variants.

Because the program must check the list and compare with the dict keys, sorting it by dict values.
As you can see, it's not necessary to match each word string as a whole, if some part of the word matches some key BEFORE the ":", it must be take into account for the sorting.

```
    texto=self.master.clipboard_get() #obtenemos un string del clipboard
    texto=texto.split('\n') #separamos cada parrafo en una entrada de una lista
    texto=list(map(str.strip,texto)) #eliminamos posibles espacios iniciales y finales en cada entrada
    N=len(texto) #medimos su longitud
    x=[] #inicializamos la lista de items no deseados
    for i in range(N): #recorremos cada elemento de la lista
        n=len(texto[i]) #longitud del elemento en cuestion
        check=texto[i]==' '*n #si el elemento es solo espacio en blanco
        if check==True:
            x.append(texto[i]) #añadimos el item no deseado
    texto = [e for e in texto if e not in x] #con esto ya tenemos la lista con las entradas a poner en los campos
    N=len(texto) #volvemos a medir su longitud
    if N>5:
        return messagebox.showerror("Atención", "El texto que desea pegar tiene más de 5 líneas. El número de campos debe ser compatible con las celdas que se desea rellenar.")
    elif N<5: #si es menor que 5 completamos campos con entradas vacias
        while len(texto)<5:
            texto.append('')
    dic=dict(organiza=1,autor=1,direct=1,docen=1,exp=1,dirig=1,ponen=1,fecha=2,día=2,dia=2,cuándo=2,cuando=2,lugar=3,sitio=3,locali=3,situa=3,direcci=3,ubica=3,web=4,link=4,enlace=4,página=4,pagina=4)#diccionario con el orden de las claves
    new_order=[i for i in range(5)] #lista que llevara los nuevos ordenes de texto
    iteracion=itertools.product(range(1,N), dic.keys())
    for i, j in iteracion: #un loop es sobre el vector texto y otro sobre las claves del diccionario
        if texto[i].lower().find(j,0,texto[i].find(':'))!=-1: #si en alguna entrada del vector texto encuentra alguna clave j antes de los :
            new_order[i]=dic[j] #en el vector de nuevas posiciones asignamos la que nos dice el diccionario
    texto=[x for _,x in sorted(zip(new_order,texto))]
    self.var_entry_titulo.set(texto[0])
    self.var_entry_director.set(texto[1][texto[1].find(':')+1:].strip())
    self.var_entry_fecha.set(texto[2][texto[2].find(':')+1:].strip())
    self.var_entry_lugar.set(texto[3][texto[3].find(':')+1:].strip())
    self.var_entry_web.set(texto[4][texto[4].find(':')+1:].strip())
    print(texto,new_order)
```

The code above doesn´t work at all. I've tried a lot but fails ever.

Thank you all, I hope you understand what I'm trying to explain, but I know it's a very poor argumentation

Comment: what about the first pair ?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by first pair?

Comment: 'TITLE', its not in that list right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dictionary in the question is missing the key for "title", which should have a value of zero because it goes first. Also, you should use the `key` parameter when calling the `sorted` procedure, it simplifies the problem quite a lot. Here's my proposal:

```
import re

# this is the preferred syntax for creating a dictionary
dic = {'title':0,'organiza':1,'autor':1,'direct':1,'docen':1,'exp':1,'dirig':1,'ponen':1,'fecha':2,'día':2,'dia':2,'cuándo':2,'cuando':2,'lugar':3,'sitio':3,'locali':3,'situa':3,'direcci':3,'ubica':3,'web':4,'link':4,'enlace':4,'página':4,'pagina':4}

def rank(ele):
    # split each element in words
    ele = ele.lower()
    words = re.split(r'[: ]+', ele)
    # check each word to see if it's a
    # substring of one of the dictionary keys
    for w in words:
        for word, value in dic.items():
            if word in w:
                # return first match
                return value
    # if no match is found, send word to the end
    return float('+inf')
```

It works as expected:

```
lis = ['TITLE:BLAH,BLAH..', 'web: www.something.es', 'situación: UCM University', 'Director: Someone', 'Fecha: some date']
sorted(lis, key=rank)
=> ['TITLE:BLAH,BLAH..', 'Director: Someone', 'Fecha: some date', 'situación: UCM University', 'web: www.something.es']
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! only one thing: TITLE does not have to include a ':', it must be ever the first element. In your code, if you type something like:

lis=[TITLE,'web',.....etc]

the output is not as I'd expected.
Appart from this, the rest is very well!!

Comment: It's a regular expression, it doesn't matter if the ":" is there or not.

Comment: Learned a new thing --> (+inf) and (nan) along with it. Thanks @Óscar

Comment: And why is better that way for creating a dictionary?

Comment: It's the widespread convention. And works on older versions of Python, your syntax does not.

Comment: @Dani My pleasure. Hey! I just realised we're both based in Madrid. It's a small world :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you can try :

```
dic=dict(organiza=1,autor=1,direct=1,docen=1,exp=1,dirig=1,ponen=1,fecha=2,día=2,dia=2,cuándo=2,cuando=2,lugar=3,sitio=3,locali=3,situa=3,direcci=3,ubica=3,web=4,link=4,enlace=4,página=4,pagina=4)
lis = ['TITLE:BLAH,BLAH..', 'web: www.something.es', 'situación: UCM University', 'Director: Someone',
   'Fecha: some date']
li = [[] for i in range(len(lis))]
li[0].append(lis[0])
for x in lis:
    for j in dic.keys():
        if j in x.split(':')[0].lower():
            li[dic[j]].append(x)

print(sum(li,[]))
# ['TITLE:BLAH,BLAH..', 'Director: Someone', 'Fecha: some date', 'situación: UCM University', 'web: www.something.es']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a sort key in order to sort by the value after ": ". The 'sort_key' function returns the string after ": ", which will be the parameter of the sort.

```
lis=['TITLE: BLAH,BLAH..', 'web: www.something.es', 'situación: UCM University', 'Director: Someone', 'Fecha: some date']
def sort_key(elem):
    return elem.split(': ')[1]
print(sorted(lis,key=sort_key))
```

Comment: Match is against a _substring_ of a dictionary key. Example: "Director" matches with the "direct" key.

Answer (score 0):

```
dic = {'title':0,'organiza':1,'autor':1,'direct':1,'docen':1,'exp':1,'dirig':1,'ponen':1,'fecha':2,'día':2,'dia':2,'cuándo':2,'cuando':2,'lugar':3,'sitio':3,'locali':3,'situa':3,'direcci':3,'ubica':3,'web':4,'link':4,'enlace':4,'página':4,'pagina':4}

lis = ['TITLE:BLAH,BLAH..', 'web: www.something.es', 'situación: UCM University', 'Director: Someone', 'Fecha: some date']

def get_ordered_add(value):
    keys = dic.keys()
    title = value.split(":")[0].lower()
    return  [dic[kys]
                 for kys in keys 
                 if title.startswith(kys)][0]

sorted(lis, key=get_ordered_add)
>>>['TITLE:BLAH,BLAH..',
    'Director: Someone',
    'Fecha: some date',
    'situaci\xc3\xb3n: UCM University',
    'web: www.something.es']
```